# JPQL Create new Object In Select Statement with collection field

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

How to retrieve list, set (One-To-Many) in JPA-query with new-operator.

For instance I have next classes:

```
 @Entity
    JobDetails {
       private String name;
       @OneToMany
       private Set<Items> items;
       private Customer c;
    }

@Entity
Customer {
   private int merchantId;
}

UserAndCustomerDto{
   private int merchantId;
   private String name;
   private Set<Items> items;

   public UserAndCustomerDto(int merchantId, String name, Set<Items> items) {
     ...
    }
}
```

Here is repository with select query:

```
 @Query("
    select new UserAndCustomerDto(
        c.merchantId,
        j.name,
        items
       ) from Job j
              left join j.c as c
              left join j.items as items
    ")
    UserAndCustomerDto findDto()
```

And exception is about invalid constructor, so
instead of building DTO using

- **`new DTO (String, int, Set < Item > )`**

it tries to build this :

- **`new DTO (String, int, Item)`**

According to doc-n it should work : [HQL Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)

How to fix this or is this possible to build this query using Hibernate Criteria ?

Comment: What happens if you don't dereference `j.items as items` and use `new UserAndCustomerDto(c.merchantId, j.name, j.items)` instead?

Comment: I will double check this, but if I am not mistaken I checked this